# Page not found (404) in django tututorial

Tags: python, django

I'm working through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/ .

after changing the urls.py to

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
      url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I get the following when I start the runserver:

```
404 error

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Comment: well looks like you were trying to hit an empty url, and you haven't defined where an empty url goes. I assume you mean not when you "start the runserver", but that you ran `manage.py runserver` and then hit localhost:8000 in the browser and got this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a base url defined. You need something like -

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    # ...
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view())

)
```

You should be able to see your site at - localhost:8000/admin/ (assuming you're running your dev server with `python manage.py runserver`).

Django checks all the URL's you've defined in your url conf file and looks for one that matches the url you've entered in the browser. If it finds a URL that matches then it serves up the http response returned by the url's corresponding view (`HomeView` in the code above). The urls.py file is matching url's to views. Views return the http response.

Looking at the error message you've got (and the code you've included from the `url.py` file), you can see that there's only one url defined in your app - `admin/`. Trying to get a page at any other url will fail.

For more information have a look at the [docs for django's URL Dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/).